# Calculate coordinetes from origin

Tags: php, coordinates

Good morning,
I need to calculate the coordinates starting from the origin using PHP,(latitude and longitude) first the black line, from the origin adding one km to 250 km then moving to the right 1.44 ° and doing the same until completing the turn (360 / 1.44 = 250), can you help me or guide me on how to do it?
Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Isn't it a question of geometry, so actually mathematics? LOL

Comment: I've just found this, maybe this helps you a bit: https://gist.github.com/duedal/840476